# Responsive grid layout breaking within media query

Tags: html, css

Need some help figuring out why the bottom images keep pushing out. I have a responsive grid layout and developing a personal webpage. Images are setup to display in a 4 column layout with a media query set up to change to a 2 column layout @ 800px. When I resize the browser width by dragging the edge, the layout breaks then resolves itself on and off every few px the window is reduced by. E.g. at 800px the layout is good, 799px it breaks, fine at 797px and so on. Why is this happening?

Link to the page HTML and CSS

```
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="VMeJMq" 
   data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="smedz28" 
   data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="Media query breaking" 
   class="codepen">See the Pen 
   <a href="https://codepen.io/smedz28/pen/VMeJMq/">Media query breaking</a> 
     by Marc Smedley (<a href="https://codepen.io/smedz28">@smedz28</a>) 
     on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen
   </a>.
</p>
<script async src="https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js">
</script>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/smedz28/pen/VMeJMq#code-area)

Comment: have you tried using bootstrap?

Comment: No, I wrote all the code myself as part of the learning curve after reading a few tutorials

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'it breaks'?  I put my screen width at 800px and 799px, and both look the same.

Comment: [link](http://i446.photobucket.com/albums/qq184/smedz28/799%20viewport_zpspii0lg7r.jpg)

Comment: Okay, your codepen link did not have any images, so I could not test the same way you do.  I think what may be the problem (not 100% sure), is that your images is wider than your container.  Reduce the width of your images to see if that solves your problem?

Comment: The images should be responsive though and only fill the width on the container as it does at other viewport sizes? when I reduce the browser window further by only a few px then the images align as they are supposed to again [link](http://i446.photobucket.com/albums/qq184/smedz28/797%20viewport_zpsujuwtnym.jpg)

Comment: somehow I cant seem to replicate this issue.  Are you using Chrome?

Comment: I get the same issue when testing in chrome and firefox. All files are on my laptop, using the dev tools in each browser to emulate the viewport sizes etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like jae.phoenix was correct with the image size in a way, it wasn't so much the container size and HTML/CSS. It was the actual image sizes that were breaking the layout.

I resized all images and the layout seems to be working perfectly

> Reduce the width of your images to see if that solves your problem? – jae.phoenix

Answer (score 0):

As the images in the codepen have no source, it is not possible to replicate the behavior.

Using the DOM inspector, all images have `max-width:100%` property defined. Due to the [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), this might lead images to be greater than 100% width, as they also have `border:3px` set.

Try adjusting the `max-width` to compensate for the borders:

```
img {
  max-width:calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

or

```
img {
  max-width:calc(100% - 6px) !important;
}
```

If you need to force an override of other selectors.

Comment: I'll give that a try and check the results